# App Store Hosted Content without in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, download

Does Apple have anything similar to their Hosted Content that does not involve an in-App Purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [On-Demand resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/) can be used without purchase. Also check the [WWDC session on it](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/214/)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use this system without having any In-App purchase. Everything is explained in the Apple's [On-Demand Resources Essentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/).

In fact, Remote storage of in-app purchase resources is just a part of the whole feature.